# Usage CURRENT_ROLE in View

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I‘m using MariaDB and what I want to archive is to limit the output of a legacy user table based on the currently set role. (Normal user only see their data, team leads can see data of team members, and management can see all data).

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE user = session_user() or current_role() = 'CEO'
```

This works fine as a statement, but not in a view definition similar to the issue with USER() vs SESSION_USER().

Is there any way to work around this issue? I‘m also open to totally different approaches.
Thx.

Using information_schema.enabled_roles doesn’t work either.

the underlying issue can be reproduced by these steps:
create role 'CEO';
set role 'CEO';

SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();
—> 'CEO'

CREATE VIEW testRole AS SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();

SELECT * FROM testRole;

—> NULL

Execute by a user with fully granted privileges;

Comment: What is the sql security clause of your view, definer or invoker?

Comment: @RohitGupta That would be useless, you could even create a view without tables to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you're using a very old version. This issue has been [fixed](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12666) long long time ago.

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW test_view AS
  SELECT USER(), CURRENT_ROLE()
```

works fine.

Comment: Awesome, works as described thank you very much!